# Where to initialize logging in a Compojure app?

Tags: logging, clojure, compojure, ring, luminus

I have a Compojure app generated using Luminus. I want to configure logging using [clj-logging-config](https://github.com/malcolmsparks/clj-logging-config) but I'm struggling mightily with this. I put the `(!set-logger)` command in the `init` function (declared with `{:ring {:init}` in `project.clj`) but I can't explain the behavior.

If I just say `(!set-logger)` then it logs stuff. If I say `(set-logger! :pattern "%d - %m%n")` then it complains:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (example.routes.home).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Setting the log level doesn't seem to have any effect.

Moving the `(!set-logger)` to the top of different modules seems to cause those modules to log as expected, but I'm failing to find the right place to put a single `(!set-logger)` with all the parameters I want and have it affect the whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to work:

```
(set-loggers!
  :root {
    :level :debug
    :pattern "%d - [%p] %m%n"
  }
)
```

My assumption was that `set-logger!` by default sets the root logger. I guess that is incorrect?

Comment: I accepted this even though I'm not 100% sure I found the right solution.